# onEndReached causing multiple items displaying on the listview

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-native

I end up having multiple items duplicate on my listview because for some reason the api is called with same param 'page=1' multiple times, also the onEndReached is firing itself without me scrolling.

I have tried something like this:

```
 componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchCategories();
 }


fetchCategories() {
   this.setState({isLoading: true});
   categoryApi.getOne(this.state.page).then(response => {
       if (response.data) {
           this.setState({
               categories: this.state.categories.concat(response.data.data),
               isLoading: false,
           });
       } else {
           this.setState({isLoading: false});
           Alert.alert(
               'Something wrong happened!',
               'My Alert Msg',
               [],
               {cancelable: true}
           )
       }
   }); }

this.state = {
     isLoading: false,
     categories: [],
     page: 1,
};

showMore = () => {
    this.setState({page: this.state.page + 1});
    this.fetchCategories();
}; 



<FlatList
  data={this.state.categories}
  extraData={this.state}
  renderItem={(rowData) => <CategoryItem navigate={navigate} item={rowData}/>}
  onEndReached={this.showMore}
  keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
 />
```

What I tried:
Changed showMore to:

```
showMore = () => {
        // console.log("End reached.");
        this.setState(prevState =>({
            page: prevState + 1
        }), () => {
            this.fetchCategories();
        });
};
```

Still I can see duplicate items for the page=1, api is still being called with parameter page = 1 multiple times!

Anyone knows how can I avoid such thing?

Comment: Did you try `onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}` ?

Comment: @PritishVaidya looks like onEndReachedThreshold={0.5} solved the problem with firing itself, but I still can see duplicate items on my list when I try to scroll, seems that my api is being called before page state is changed, so basically the page value is not incremented in time!

Comment: You're trying to concat the data here `this.state.categories.concat(response.data.data)` therefore it is adding it to the array, instead you should merge the array.

Comment: so u saying instead of .concat() i should use .merge() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `onEndReachedThreshold` in conjunction with `onEndReached` to prevent the weird behavior from happening

As mentioned in the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#onendreached)

> `onEndReached` : Called once when the scroll position gets within `onEndReachedThreshold` of the rendered content.

Therefore you may set the value as `onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}`

*`0.5` will trigger `onEndReached` when the end of the content is within half the visible length of the list*

For deduping the items you need to merge them as [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) combines two arrays with or without unique values.

Therefore as usual, you can use the `es6 spread operator`

Example

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
let arr2 = [3, 5, 6];

let deDupeIt = (...arrs) => [ ...new Set( [].concat(...arrs) ) ];

let dedupedArrays = deDupeIt(arr1, arr2)
console.log(dedupedArrays)
```

In your case define the function somewhere and call it as

```
this.setState({
               categories: deDupeIt(this.state.categories, response.data.data),
               isLoading: false,
           });
```

**Note:**

If you're using the second part of your code snippet
`prevState.page + 1` should be used and not `prevState + 1`

Comment: are u saying that insteadl of categories: this.state.categories.concat(response.data.data), I should have  


let deDupeIt = (...arrs) => [ ...new Set( [].concat(...arrs) ) ];

let dedupedArrays = deDupeIt(this.state.categories, response.data.data)

this.state.categories.concat(dedupedArrays)
?

Comment: Updated, try it like that wherever you're `concating`

Comment: i did the same thing what you suggested, I can still see duplicate items.

Comment: Can you add `response objects` for the items, containing some `duplicates`, i think it might the problem for nested duplicate objects in items.

Comment: i think the problem was not with concat at all, the problem is my api call is called twice with the same param page:1

Comment: so basically this.state.page + 1 in showMore is not being updated before the next Api call  happens!

Comment: If you're using the second part of the code you might need to try with this `page: prevState.page + 1` here.

Comment: u mean like:   this.setState(prevState =>({
            page: prevState + 1
        }), () => {
            this.fetchCategories();
        });

Comment: `prevState.page + 1` should be used and not  `prevState + 1`

Comment: can u update your answer abit with this solution so I can accept it?